# When I click on HOME in Prestashop I want to go to my main product page

Tags: php, prestashop

Thanks to Jon Lin I was able to Redirect my PRESTASHOP site to go to the PRODUCT page instead of the HOME page when someone clicks on my site URL.

As of now I have only 1 product on my site so I always want to go to that PRODUCT page.

However now, when someone is on my site and they are on some other page, maybe in the cart..., and they click on HOME I would like to have them go back to the main PRODUCT page.  NOT the actual HOME page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use .htaccess to redirect to the product page.

Comment: I already use RedirectMatch in the .htaccess to redirect my site URL to the product page.  But once I'm inside my site I'm not sure what command or how to change HOME to go to my product page.

Answer (score 0):

In the configurations, in SEO and URLs, change the base uri to your product page.

Comment: When I put the product url in the base url it breaks something in the site.  It loses all the formatting.  What comes up is just text with my site info.  It is just text down the left side of the screen.  Not sure why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to fix. Lets consider your product product id is 5 and also ignore the SEO friendly urls at the moment. Open the file **controllers/front/IndexController.php**  and add the following code somewhere in the only **initContent** function.

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?id_product=5&controller=product');
```

Now when ever some comes to home page of the site, that user will be redirected to the product page. If SEO friendly urls are enabled, then prestashop will automatically display SEO url in the address bar of the prestashop for that particular product.

Mode dev must be set to false

Please change id_product 5 to your product id.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect method is good if you absolutely must go to your category, however I have an alternative method. For SEO reasons I believe you should not do a redirect. What I would do is I would add homefeatured module to your homepage and add pagination to it, making it just like a category. First off I would make a backup of your homefeatured files in the core and your theme before testing, however this worked for me on 1.5.4 version.

You can do so by adding a file named `paginationHomeFeatured.tpl` to `./themes/yourtheme/modules/homefeatured/<HERE>` with the following code..

```
{*
* 2007-2012 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2012 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*}
{if isset($no_follow) AND $no_follow}
{assign var='no_follow_text' value='rel="nofollow"'}
{else}
{assign var='no_follow_text' value=''}
{/if}
{if isset($p) AND $p}
  {assign var='requestPage' value=$base_dir|cat:'index.php'}
  {assign var='requestNb' value=$base_dir|cat:'index.php'}
{* {assign var='requestNb' value=$smarty.section.pagination.limits} *}

<!-- Pagination -->
<div id="pagination" class="pagination">
{if $start!=$stop}
  <ul class="pagination">
  {if $p != 1}
   {assign var='p_previous' value=$p-1}
   <li id="pagination_previous"><a {$no_follow_text} href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $p_previous)}">&laquo;&nbsp;{l s='Previous'}</a></li>
  {else}
   <li id="pagination_previous" class="disabled"><span>&laquo;&nbsp;{l s='Previous'}</span></li>
  {/if}
  {if $start==3}
   <li><a {$no_follow_text}  href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, 1)}">1</a></li>
   <li><a {$no_follow_text}  href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, 2)}">2</a></li>
  {/if}
  {if $start==2}
   <li><a {$no_follow_text}  href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, 1)}">1</a></li>
  {/if}
  {if $start>3}
   <li><a {$no_follow_text}  href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, 1)}">1</a></li>
   <li class="truncate">...</li>
  {/if}
  {section name=pagination start=$start loop=$stop+1 step=1}
   {if $p == $smarty.section.pagination.index}
    <li class="current"><span>{$p|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span></li>
   {else}
    <li><a {$no_follow_text} href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $smarty.section.pagination.index)}">{$smarty.section.pagination.index|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
   {/if}
  {/section}
  {if $pages_nb>$stop+2}
   <li class="truncate">...</li>
   <li><a href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $pages_nb)}">{$pages_nb|intval}</a></li>
  {/if}
  {if $pages_nb==$stop+1}
   <li><a href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $pages_nb)}">{$pages_nb|intval}</a></li>
  {/if}
  {if $pages_nb==$stop+2}
   <li><a href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $pages_nb-1)}">{$pages_nb-1|intval}</a></li>
   <li><a href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $pages_nb)}">{$pages_nb|intval}</a></li>
  {/if}
  {if $pages_nb > 1 AND $p != $pages_nb}
   {assign var='p_next' value=$p+1}
   <li id="pagination_next"><a {$no_follow_text} href="{$link->goPage($requestPage, $p_next)}">{l s='Next'}&nbsp;&raquo;</a></li>
  {else}
   <li id="pagination_next" class="disabled"><span>{l s='Next'}&nbsp;&raquo;</span></li>
  {/if}
  </ul>
{/if}
{if $nb_products > $products_per_page}
  <form action="{if !is_array($requestNb)}{$requestNb}{else}{$requestNb.requestUrl}{/if}" method="get" class="pagination">
   <p>
    {if isset($search_query) AND $search_query}<input type="hidden" name="search_query" value="{$search_query|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
    {if isset($tag) AND $tag AND !is_array($tag)}<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="{$tag|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
    <input type="submit" class="button_mini" value="{l s='OK'}" />
    <label for="nb_item">{l s='items:'}</label>
    <select name="n" id="nb_item">
    {assign var="lastnValue" value="0"}
    {foreach from=$nArray item=nValue}
         {if $lastnValue <= $nb_products}
          <option value="{$nValue|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $n == $nValue}selected="selected"{/if}>{$nValue|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
         {/if}
         {assign var="lastnValue" value=$nValue}
    {/foreach}
    </select>
    {if is_array($requestNb)}
         {foreach from=$requestNb item=requestValue key=requestKey}
          {if $requestKey != 'requestUrl'}
           <input type="hidden" name="{$requestKey|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" value="{$requestValue|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
          {/if}
         {/foreach}
    {/if}
   </p>
  </form>
{/if}
</div>
<!-- /Pagination -->
{/if}
```

Next, change homefeatured.tpl to..

```
{*
* 2007-2013 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2013 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*}

<!-- MODULE Home Featured Products -->
<div id="featured-products_block_center" class="block products_block clearfix">
    <p class="title_block">{l s='Featured products' mod='homefeatured'}</p>
    {if isset($products) AND $products}
        <div class="block_content">
            {assign var='liHeight' value=250}
            {assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=4}
            {assign var='nbLi' value=$products|@count}
            {math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLine" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=nbLines}
            {math equation="nbLines*liHeight" nbLines=$nbLines|ceil liHeight=$liHeight assign=ulHeight}
            <ul style="height:{$ulHeight}px;">
            {foreach from=$products item=product name=homeFeaturedProducts}
                {math equation="(total%perLine)" total=$smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.total perLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=totModulo}
                {if $totModulo == 0}{assign var='totModulo' value=$nbItemsPerLine}{/if}
                <li class="ajax_block_product {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.last}last_item{else}item{/if} {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 0}last_item_of_line{elseif $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 1} {/if} {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration > ($smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.total - $totModulo)}last_line{/if}">
                    <a href="{$product.link}" title="{$product.name|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" class="product_image"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')}" height="{$homeSize.height}" width="{$homeSize.width}" alt="{$product.name|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" />{if isset($product.new) && $product.new == 1}<span class="new">{l s='New' mod='homefeatured'}</span>{/if}</a>
                    <p class="s_title_block"><a href="{$product.link}" title="{$product.name|truncate:50:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></p>
                    <div class="product_desc"><a href="{$product.link}" title="{l s='More' mod='homefeatured'}">{$product.description_short|strip_tags|truncate:65:'...'}</a></div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="lnk_more" href="{$product.link}" title="{l s='View' mod='homefeatured'}">{l s='View' mod='homefeatured'}</a>
                        {if $product.show_price AND !isset($restricted_country_mode) AND !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}<p class="price_container"><span class="price">{if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}</span></p>{else}<div style="height:21px;"></div>{/if}

                        {if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 OR (isset($add_prod_display) AND ($add_prod_display == 1))) AND $product.available_for_order AND !isset($restricted_country_mode) AND $product.minimal_quantity == 1 AND $product.customizable != 2 AND !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            {if ($product.quantity > 0 OR $product.allow_oosp)}
                            <a class="exclusive ajax_add_to_cart_button" rel="ajax_id_product_{$product.id_product}" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart')}?qty=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product}&amp;token={$static_token}&amp;add" title="{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}">{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}</a>
                            {else}
                            <span class="exclusive">{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}</span>
                            {/if}
                        {else}
                            <div style="height:23px;"></div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {else}
        <p>{l s='No featured products' mod='homefeatured'}</p>
    {/if}

    {* To add pagination - add three line below *}
    <div class="content_sortPagiBar homefeaturedPaged">
        {include file="./paginationHomeFeatured.tpl"}
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /MODULE Home Featured Products -->
```

Lastly, edit homefeatured.php in your core directory.

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2013 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2013 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class HomeFeatured extends Module
{
    private $_html = '';
    private $_postErrors = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'homefeatured';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '0.9';
        $this->author = 'PrestaShop';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Featured products on the homepage.');
        $this->description = $this->l('Displays featured products in the middle of your homepage.');
    }

    function install()
    {
        if (!Configuration::updateValue('HOME_FEATURED_NBR', 8) || !parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayHome') || !$this->registerHook('header'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = '<h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>';
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitHomeFeatured'))
        {
            $nbr = (int)(Tools::getValue('nbr'));
            if (!$nbr OR $nbr <= 0 OR !Validate::isInt($nbr))
                $errors[] = $this->l('An invalid number of products has been specified.');
            else
                Configuration::updateValue('HOME_FEATURED_NBR', (int)($nbr));
            if (isset($errors) AND sizeof($errors))
                $output .= $this->displayError(implode('<br />', $errors));
            else
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Your settings have been updated.'));
        }
        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }

    public function displayForm()
    {
        $output = '
        <form action="'.Tools::safeOutput($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'" method="post">
            <fieldset><legend><img src="'.$this->_path.'logo.gif" alt="" title="" />'.$this->l('Settings').'</legend>
                <p>'.$this->l('To add products to your homepage, simply add them to the "home" category.').'</p><br />
                <label>'.$this->l('Define the number of products to be displayed.').'</label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="nbr" value="'.Tools::safeOutput(Tools::getValue('nbr', (int)(Configuration::get('HOME_FEATURED_NBR')))).'" />
                    <p class="clear">'.$this->l('Define the number of products that you would like to display on homepage (default: 8).').'</p>

                </div>
                <center><input type="submit" name="submitHomeFeatured" value="'.$this->l('Save').'" class="button" /></center>
            </fieldset>
        </form>';
        return $output;
    }

    public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
    {
        $this->hookHeader($params);
    }

    public function hookHeader($params)
    {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'homefeatured.css', 'all');
    }

    public function hookDisplayHome($params)
    {
/*      $category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
        $nb = (int)(Configuration::get('HOME_FEATURED_NBR'));
        $products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'products' => $products,
            'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
            'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
        ));

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'homefeatured.tpl');
*/



        $controller = new FrontController();
            $controller->productSort();
        $category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
            $nbProducts = $category->getProducts(NULL, NULL, NULL, $controller->orderBy, $controller->orderWay, true);
        $controller->pagination($nbProducts);

        $this->smarty->assign('nb_products', $nbProducts);

        $products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, (int)($controller->p),
                (int)($controller->n), $controller->orderBy, $controller->orderWay);

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'products' => $products,
                'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
                'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
                'id_category' => (int)($category->id),
                'id_category_parent' => (int)($category->id_parent),
                'return_category_name' => Tools::safeOutput($category->name),
                'path' => Tools::getPath((int)($category->id), $category->name)
                ));

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'homefeatured.tpl');












    }
}
```

That would be my solution to avoid a redirect on the homepage. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. In my case, I changed the home page to another URL which is mine. Other product pages still work normal. To do that, go to **controllers/front/IndexController.php** and change add the following code somewhere in the **initContent function**.

```
Tools::redirect('http://newwebsiteurl.com/');
```

That is you will delete all the contents in the function below

```
{
    parent::initContent();
    $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'index.js');

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('HOOK_HOME' => Hook::exec('displayHome'),
        'HOOK_HOME_TAB' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTab'),
        'HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTabContent')
    ));
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
}
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
 {
    parent::initContent();

    Tools::redirect('http://newwebsiteurl.com/');

}
```

It worked for me on my website [Soup Embassy](https://mysoupembassy.com) and I hope does for you too. If you check the URL on [Soup Category](http://mysoupembassy.com/buy-online/13-where-to-buy-soup-online) here, you will see that it is in a directory /buy-online/ and when you click on the home link or logo, it will redirect you to a URL without the extension. I hope you find this helpful.